# Python iterate through pixels of image

Tags: python, image, typeerror

I'm trying to iterate through pixels of an image. I set the size and then use a for loop, however I get a type error: object not iterable. I have imported PIL and Image

```
w=100
h=200
im=im.resize((w,h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
for a in w:
    for b in h:
    (...)
```

Comment: `for pixel in im.getdata():` prehaps?

Comment: or `for a in range(w): for b in range(h):`

Comment: Did you try reading the traceback? It should point you to the offending line.

Comment: thank you for your replies! I am new to Python and this helped solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type error issue is coming from the fact that `w` and `h` and integers and therefore cannot be iterated through. The construct `for i in thing:` loops through every item in `thing`, so if `thing` is a list `[2, 5, 6]`, for example, `i` will be 2 and then 5 and then 6.

What you want is `for a in range(w)` and `for b in range(h)`, which will allow you to iterate through all integers from 0 to `w` or `h`.